# grep whole file and tail it without using "line-buffered" option in grep

Tags: shell, grep, tail, busybox

I have BusyBox v1.21.0 installed and it has got very basic grep operation, no --line-buffered  option

```
grep sync_complete /var/log/messages
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep sync_complete
```

is it possible to combine above commands into single line command? thanks!

Comment: Is tail command not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-n +1` to make tail read the file from the start:

```
tail -n +1 -f /var/log/messages | grep sync_complete
```